# How to parse time in Salesforce Visualforce, Apex?

Tags: datetime, salesforce, visualforce

I'm quite new to visualforce/apex programming and kinda stuck in parsing <strike>current</strike> time and time functions in apex.

Basically I'm trying to figure out if the current time is within my given time range.
How do I write this in apex language?

```
public String isWorkhours;
public String getIsWorkhours() { 
    Datetime current_time = *(get current time)*
    Datetime start_time = *(7:00 am)*
    Datetime end_time = *(7:00 pm)*

    if ((current_time >= start_time) && (current_time <= end_time)) {
        isWorkhours= 'yes';
    } else {
        isWorkhours= 'no';
    }
    return isWorkhours;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - check if you can use Business Hours (standard object) to configure SF instead of writing similar functionality manually. Just check your online help for these.

Example of comparison of 2 datetime objects: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_businesshours.htm

Secondly - read the [reference of Time class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_time.htm). Something like this?

```
Time start = Time.newInstance(7,0,0,0), stop = Time.newInstance(19,0,0,0);

DateTime now = System.now(); // or DateTime.now();

System.debug(now.time() > start && now.time() < stop);
```

Comment: The Business hours object did it for me. Thanks eyescream.

Comment: Ha! the less code the better, always good to use something standard. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Also referred to this post to find out if current time is within business hours. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/method-to-check-whether-a-date-is-a-holiday